# A riddle after low and after

Tags: riddle, visual

The images below are connected by a single word:

[image: A Circle]

[image: A Jacket Potato]

[image: Words forming common structure.]

[image: A Security Guard]

[image: A Retro Motorcycle]

[image: A common-block-compatible-people resembling the band KISS]

[image: Dun-dun, Dun-dun - Jaws]

[image: A Guy with style]

[image: A Shelf]

What is the word, and what are the connections? (words + common phases/idioms)

Comment: Just to clarify...is it the same word for all connections or a different word for each?

Comment: Same word . @drt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Life

As in...

> Circle of life, life jacket (potato) (via BeastlyGerbil), life guard, life cycle (TwoBitOperation), kiss of life, jaws of life, life style (also TwoBitOperation), and shelf life.

OP: You only missed

> life sentence

Which was a bit sneaky so well done...

Comment: Life jacket for the potato

Comment: I'd go with 'Life Cycle' instead of 'Motorcycle life.'  Also, the one of Psy could be 'Life Style' since he is dancing Gangnam Style?

Comment: Also, the title shows that this answer is probably right due to "Low Life" and "Afterlife"

Comment: Revealing in comments what is spoilered in an answer makes the spoilering rather pointless. Please preserve the mystery. :)

Comment: @Rubio: Get a rot13(yvsr)! `:)`

Comment: @MOehm Synttrq nf ehqr be nohfvir :)

Comment: Never heard of a jacket potato (you wacky Brits!).

Comment: @APrough REALLY?!  Huh...  I thought that one would've crossed the pond.

Comment: @BrentHackers - It may have, but in the areas I have lived it is always referred to as a "baked potato".  Oh, well, I like "jacket" better, so I am going to adopt the term from now on.

Comment: @APrough When I think about it we (or I) use Jacket and Baked interchangeably... hope that's not another Americanism I've picked up...  I was in my teens before I learned the awful historic truth and began correcting my pronunciation of 'Z(-ed)', among other things...  Words can and should be changed over time for many valid reasons but making them rhyme with "V" is not one of them!  SUPERFLUOUS RANT!

Answer (score 0):

This also fits [partial answer].

> Political

Here it goes

> Political Circle
> Political Hot potato 
> ---
> Political Guardian
> ---
> ---
> Political Mask --> The picture is JAWS Mask
> Political Psychology
> Political Stand